# 301 redirect out of domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain `www.domain1.com` that points to the root folder of my site and another domain `www.domain2.com` configured like redirector to `www.dominio1.com.br/new`.

All fine, but I would like that, when someone accesses `www.domain2.com`, it's will still see `www.domain2.com` in the adress bar, not `www.domain1.com.br/new`.

I have never worked with linux server before, but I saw that I can do this kind of thing with the `.htaccess` file, but I don't know how.

Can anyone help me, please?

By the way, in my `htaccess` file in the `public_html\new` folder already existis the following WordPress content, that I believe maintains the friendly URLs:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy installed?

Comment: Yes, I have mod_proxy..

Answer (score 0):

If you have mod_proxy loaded, just add this to the htaccess file in domain2's document root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dominio1.com.br/new%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

near the top

Comment: I tried to add this above the code of WordPress in the `htaccess` file on the target folder of the domain 2, but didn't work.. The redirection works but the URL keeps changing to `www.domain1.com/new'. I got in touch with my server admin to confirm if `mod_proxy` is enabled. I'll have the answer tomorrow. Before this, any more suggestions?

Comment: Yep, I confirmed that the `mod_proxy` is enabled on the server, but this code didn't work for me.

Comment: @CassioMilanelo Are you sure something at dominio1.com isn't redirecting you?

Comment: Well, in my hosting administrator, I've set `www.domain2.com` to redirect to `dominio1.com/new` .. There is another way (or a right way) to do this?

Comment: @CassioMilanelo If you've created a redirect, it's going to redirect no matter what you have in htaccess.

Comment: I really want to redirect @JonLin. I just want the URL to keep `www.domain2.com` too...

Comment: @CassioMilanelo when you redirect **you change what is in the URL address bar**. A redirect is telling the browser to go and load an entirely different URL. This is why I asked about mod_proxy

Comment: And there is no way to do this redirect without modifying the URL, like a mask, I mean? As if the person did not know that is being redirected..

Comment: @CassioMilanelo that's what the rules in my answer does, it uses a *proxy*, what you have setup in your hosting administrator is a redirect, you need to get rid of that

Comment: Hmm .. Okay, now I get it. Just tell me what to do next with my domain. I mean, how do for people who access `www.domain2.com` be forwarded to the `root/new` folder on my server? Really sorry for my ignorance, but I have no knowledge in the area of servers.